# How to handle -0x7880 correctly in mbedtls client?

Tags: tls1.2, ftps, mbedtls

I have a working mbedtls FTPS client implementation based on `mbedtls`. However, as soon as the file transfer over the data connection finished, the server (`vsftpd`) terminates the data connection and the client prints `MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_PEER_CLOSE_NOTIFY` (-0x7880) errors:

```
tls                 : error  : [2021/09/15 18:26:32.820] [id =      6]: ../../src/../externals/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ssl_tls.c(4369): mbedtls_ssl_handle_message_t
ype() returned -30848 (-0x7880)

tls                 : error  : [2021/09/15 18:26:32.820] [id =      7]: ../../src/../externals/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ssl_tls.c(8335): mbedtls_ssl_read_record() returned -30848
 (-0x7880)
```

The file transfer however finished correctly and the data was written to a file as expected. How should this be handled correctly so that these messages do not appear? Why are they marked “error”?
The server terminating the connection after successful data transmission is correct behavior, is it not?

I have a previous post about this on : https://forums.mbed.com/t/how-to-handle-0x7880-correctly/14597 and will make sure to keep any answers in sync between the two threads!